# Constructing Multidimensional Array from Joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling for a couple of weeks tryin to figure out how can I properly construcy my multidimensional array from joined tables to my desired output.. The  parent data is repeating insted of its child..

Table

```
Business  
_________  
business_id  
business_name   

Images
___________  
image_id  
image_path
parent_id (business_id)
```

QUERY

```
SELECT business_id, business_name, image_id, image_path parent_id
  FROM business LEFT JOIN images ON business_id = parent_id
```

OUTPUT

> business id:1
>   business_name:some business_name
>   image
>      image_id:1
>      image_path: some image path
>      parent_id:1
>
> business id:1
>   business_name:some business_name
>   image
>      image_id:2
>      image_path: some image path
>      parent_id:1
>
> business id:2
>   business_name:some business_name
>   image
>      image_id:3
>      image_path: some image path
>      parent_id:2

Expected Output

> business id:1
>   business_name:some business_name
>   image
>      image_id:1
>      image_path: some image path
>      parent_id:1
>
> image_id:2
>      image_path: some image path
>      parent_id:1

Comment: please make it as a input table and expected result table

Comment: Did you take a look at the php function array_reduce?

Comment: No, I never tried it before.. how can i associate that function to my problem sir?

Comment: You expect the column `image_id` to contain 1 AND 2, that's wrong, you need to adapt your application or queries to deal with a tabular result

Comment: So what can you suggest to my problem sir Clement..

Comment: You should handle the result in php to build your array. just add the "ORDER BY business_id, Image_id" in your query, and in php you loop through the results and add all images belong to the same business_id to the same array. When another business_id is reached, start another array.